# Amazon SQS Legacy Profile Format Warning

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services

I am posting messages to a Amazon SQS queue.  At start up, I am getting the following warning in my logs.

```
[http-nio-9090-exec-2][BasicProfileConfigLoader] The legacy profile format 
requires the 'profile ' prefix before the profile name. The latest code does 
not require such prefix, and will consider it as part of the profile name. 
Please remove the prefix if you are seeing this warning.
```

I am using the following version of Amazon SQS with Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.125</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is most likely referring to your config file that is holding part of your aws credentials. Where this is on your machine will depend on what OS you are using, but for example on my Mac it is in \users\myname.aws\config

The old format was like this (as example):

```
[profile <profilename>]
region=us-east-1
output=json
```

and now should look like this instead:

```
[<profilename>]
region=us-east-1
output=json
```

Comment: This solved the problem.  By removing the word "profile" from my aws config file it removed the warning from my logs.  On my Windows 10 machine, the aws config was located at C:\Users\MyName\.aws\config.

Comment: @CaleSweeney yeah, I did the same as you said & it worked.

Comment: This worked for me as well, from my application point of view.  However, from the AWS CLI commands aws s3 ls looks for the profile keyword.  I am still on the AWS CLI 1.# could be the problem, just be advised.